# Unable to use margins inside CSS grid

Tags: html, css, margin, css-grid

I am trying to build a CSS grid layout with margins around the elements within the grid cells. However, severeal problems arise…

**Here is my code:**

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.grida{
 position:fixed;
 left:0; top:29px; width:100%;
 height:calc(100% - 29px);
 overflow:hidden;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:134px 34% auto;
}

.wrapa{
 padding-top:5px;
 background:#eee;
 margin:5px;
 border:2px solid green;
 border-radius:9px;
}

.inpsearch, .inptags{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 line-height:21px;
 outline:none;
 padding:0 9px;
 background:white;
 margin:5px;
 border:2px ridge gold;
 border-radius:9px;
}

.titles{
 height:calc(100% - 40px);
 overflow-y:scroll;
 padding:9px 0;
 margin:5px;
 border:2px ridge gold;
 border-radius:5px;
}

.storytxt{
 display:block;
 padding:14px;
 width:100%;
 height:calc(100% - 40px);
 outline:none;
 resize:none;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 background:#eee;
 margin:5px;
 border:2px ridge gold;
 border-radius:9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
<div class='wrapa'>
<div class='lang'>lorem</div>
<div class='lang'>lorem</div>
<div class='lang'>lorem</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapb'>
<input type='search' class='inpsearch' placeholder='SEARCH'>
<div class='titles'>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapc'>
<input type='text' class='inptags' placeholder='TAGS'>
<textarea class='storytxt'></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

**These are my problems:**

Why is there no space between the HTML elements with classes `inpsearch` and `inptags`?  (in the upper part of the visual output)
Why are parts of the HTML elements with classes `inptags` and `storytxt` not visible on the right?  (int the lower part of the visual output)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this way.

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.grida{
 position:fixed;
 left:0; top:29px; width:100%;
 height:calc(100% - 29px);
 overflow:hidden;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:134px 34% auto;
}

.wrapa{
 padding-top:5px;
 background:#eee;
 margin:5px;
 border:2px solid green;
 border-radius:9px;
}

.wrapb, wrapc{
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.inpsearch, .inptags{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 line-height:21px;
 outline:none;
 padding:0 9px;
 background:white;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 border:2px ridge gold;
 border-radius:9px;
}

.titles{
 height:calc(100% - 40px);
 overflow-y:scroll;
 padding:9px 0;
 border:2px ridge gold;
 border-radius:5px;
}

.storytxt{
 display:block;
 padding:14px;
 width:100%;
 height:calc(100% - 40px);
 outline:none;
 resize:none;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 background:#eee;
 border:2px ridge gold;
 border-radius:9px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class='grida'>
<div class='wrapa'>
<div class='lang'>lorem</div>
<div class='lang'>lorem</div>
<div class='lang'>lorem</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapb'>
<input type='search' class='inpsearch' placeholder='SEARCH'>
<div class='titles'>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapc'>
<input type='text' class='inptags' placeholder='TAGS'>
<textarea class='storytxt'></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So you need to:

- add to `wrapb` and `wrapc` a padding: `padding: 0 10px`
- remove the margin from `titles` and `storytxt`
- replace `margin: 5px` in `inpsearch` and `inptags` with `margin-bottom: 5px`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you cannot properly use `margin` in css grid. However, you can use `grid-gap` to introduce the `5px` `margin`. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap). (Well, I did not found a solution with `margin`s but I am a CSS novice after all :-) !)

**EDIT**
The problem with your `storytxt` is that the margin is added on top of the width which is set to `100%` through `width` and `display: block`. I accounted for this by using `width: calc(100% - 10px)` with a `margin` of `5px`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grida {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 29px);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 134px 34% auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.wrapa {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.wrapb,
.wrapc {
  border: 0px black solid;
  /* used for debugging */
}

.inpsearch,
.inptags {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 21px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 9px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.titles {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 9px 0;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.storytxt {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #eee;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
  <div class='wrapa'>
    <div class='lang'>lorem</div>
    <div class='lang'>lorem</div>
    <div class='lang'>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapb'>
    <input type='search' class='inpsearch' placeholder='SEARCH'>
    <div class='titles'>
      <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapc'>
    <input type='text' class='inptags' placeholder='TAGS'>
    <textarea class='storytxt'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this post helped you! Thanks!

Comment: and what about `storytxt`? why its left margin is larger and is not visible entire on the right side?

Comment: @puerto I updated my answer to account for the `storytxt`. Hope it helps!

Comment: now `inpsearch` and `inptags` are not equal with `titles` and `storytxt`